# Getting errors in Websocket server Endpoint

Tags: java, websocket

This is file and I am getting compilation error in `import javax.websocket` lines and in `@serverEndpoint("/websocket")`. Why it is not taking the annotation?

```
package pack.exp;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/websocket")
public class Hello 
{
{

      private static Set<Session> clients = 
        Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());

      @OnMessage
      public void onMessage(String message, Session session) 
        throws IOException {

        synchronized(clients){
          // Iterate over the connected sessions
          // and broadcast the received message
          for(Session client : clients){
            if (!client.equals(session)){
              client.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
            }
          }
        }

      }

      @OnOpen
      public void onOpen (Session session) {
      // Add session to the connected sessions set
        clients.add(session);
      }

      @OnClose
      public void onClose (Session session) {
        // Remove session from the connected sessions set
        clients.remove(session);
      }

    }
}
```

Please Help me with this error. Are there some specific api which I have to implement in this code?

Comment: Add the stack trace here.

Comment: @  Kugathasan Abimara
1.The import javax.websocket cannot be resolved
2.ServerEndpoint cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: You need to add that library jar in the classpath.

Comment: @ Kugathasan Abimaran
Ok, can you tell me which jar files are needed and from where i can download them

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The missing classes are part of the java ee 7 api.
If you are building your project with maven, take a look
at the following repository

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/7.0

and add this dependency to your project:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax</groupId>
<artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
<version>7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are not using maven, you can download the jar from the page above.
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/javaee-api/7.0/javaee-api-7.0.jar

Then you have the API.

Comment: use http://search.maven.org/  for the official maven central repository search, its also much more up to date :)

Answer (score 6):

The classes under the `javax.websocket` are defined by the JSR-356 to be standalone.  They can run on a completely standalone server or from within a Java EE 7 container.

If you are using just `javax.websocket` and don't care about the rest of Java EE 7, then just use the official `javax.websocket` artifacts in a provided scope.

Here's the search lookup directly to the artifact.

https://search.maven.org/artifact/javax.websocket/javax.websocket-api/1.0/bundle

That is the official search page for the maven central repository system, it also includes build system references to that artifact for maven, grails, ivy, buildr, grape, and sbt.

The maven pom reference would be:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Make sure you *do not* include this artifact in your `*.war` file, as this functionality will be provided by whatever container you decide to deploy into.  (Such as Eclipse Jetty 9.1+ or Apache Tomcat 8.0+)

Answer (score 0):

You can freshly add the server say tomcat 7.0, automatically this error will be resolved. As the supporting jars are available in tomcat lib.

Comment: I think OP is trying to resolve the issue without reinstalling the server.

Comment: I am not aware at all, i guess that would be a great approach without adding the server again.this worked for me,so i just suggested. @andy