# WebSocket- "Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404" when added external jar to the project

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jar, websocket

I am building simple chatting application using WebSocket using Eclipse and apache 7.x .However I am not able to compile my code cause it shows **import javax.websocket cannot be resolved**. After Googling a lot i found [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038100/getting-errors-in-websocket-server-endpoint) that shows external jar in application. I added a jar in my library section. It removed my current error but gave another. Now it showing **WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/WebSocket/socket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404**

---

I'v tried a lot like adding servlet-api.jar to build path from apache lib. And also find some information like **It provides also the javax.websocket-api-1.0.jar library so this is not needed in you application. You might need it at compile time but the server will provide it at runtime**

Now I got stuck like in recursion. when I remove my jar got first error and when I add external jar then got second error. please help me in this issue cause we are developing mini project for real time collaborative editor and we are suppose to use websocket in it.

---

Now here is my code for websocket(not using maven):

**WebSocket.java**

```
package com.psl.service;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONWriter;


@ServerEndpoint("/socket")
public class WebSocket {
Set<Session> sessionSet = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>());

@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session webSession) {
    System.out.println("Opened");
    sessionSet.add(webSession);
}

@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String message, Session webSession) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Got message    "+message);
    String username = (String)webSession.getUserProperties().get("username");
    if(username==null) {
        webSession.getUserProperties().put("username", message);
        webSession.getBasicRemote().sendText(buildJSON(username, message));
    }
    else {
        for(Session s : sessionSet) {
            s.getBasicRemote().sendText(buildJSON(username, message));
        }
    }
}


private String buildJSON(String string, String string2) {
    String jsonData="";
    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
      try {
        obj.put("message",string + ":" + string2);
        StringWriter out = new StringWriter();

          JSONWriter jwriter = new JSONWriter(out);
          jwriter.key(string).value(string2);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

      return null;
}
@OnClose
public void onClose() {
    System.out.println("CLosed");
    sessionSet.remove(sessionSet);
}

}
```

**chat.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/WebSocketDemo/socket");

    websocket.onmessage = function onMessage(message) {
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(message.data);
        if(jsonData.message != null) {
            messageTextArea.value += jsonData.message + "\n";
        }
    }
    function sendMessage() {
        websocket.send(sendText.value);
        sendText.value = "";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<textarea rows="30" cols="70" id="messageTextArea" ></textarea><br /><br />
<input id="sendText">
<input type="button" value="Send" onclick="sendMessage()">


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer for this query. This is because the added jar overrides my internal jars in apache tomcat. And I am using older tomcat that have not **websocket-api.jar**

So My solution for this problem is either use glashfish 4.x or else use apache tomcat 8.x that gives us required jar to run websocket. No need to add any extra websocket api jar.